# DataFrame of objects `astype(float)` behaviour different depending if lists or arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'll preface this with the statement that I wouldn't do this in the first place and that I ran across this helping a friend.

Consider the data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([[1.2]]))

df

       0
0  [1.2]
```

This is a data frame of objects where the objects are lists.  In my friend's code, they had:

```
df.astype(float)
```

Which breaks as I had hoped

> ```
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
> ```

However, if those values were numpy arrays instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([np.array([1.2])]))

df

       0
0  [1.2]
```

And I tried the same thing:

```
df.astype(float)

     0
0  1.2
```

It's happy enough to do something and convert my 1-length arrays to scalars.  This feels very dirty!

If instead they were not 1-length arrays

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([np.array([1.2, 1.3])]))

df

            0
0  [1.2, 1.3]
```

Then it breaks

> ```
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
> ```

---

**Question**
Please tell me this is a bug and we can fix it.  Or can someone explain why and in what world this makes sense?

---

**Response to @root**
You are right.  Is this worth an issue?  Do you expect/want this?

```
a = np.empty((1,), object)
a[0] = np.array([1.2])

a.astype(float)

array([ 1.2])
```

And

```
a = np.empty((1,), object)
a[0] = np.array([1.2, 1.3])

a.astype(float)
```

> ```
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
> ```

Comment: Behind the scenes `df.astype(float)` is basically doing `df._values.astype(float)`, and then passing that back to through the constructor [(here)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L4444-L4447).  In this case `df._values` is an `object` dtype array containing the single element array, so looks like some numpy weirdness is causing this.

Comment: @root if you didn't already see.  I've responded via the post.

Comment: What you'd _expect_ is that `a.astype(float)` tries to replace each element `a[i]` with `float(a[i])`. For your former test this would exactly reproduce the array you get (cf. `float(np.array([1.2]))`). For your latter test you'd try executing `float(np.array([1.2, 1.3]))`, which in itself would raise an error, albeit a different kind of error: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. But the amount-of-brokenness, so to speak, is there: it doesn't make sense to try to coerce a non-scalar-compatible array-like to `float`.

Comment: @piRSquared: yeah, I'd consider this a bug, since I'd expect consistent behavior of raising (note that the same setup with a length zero array also raises).  Couldn't hurt to open an issue.  Not all that familiar with the numpy codebase, so not sure about the feasibility/implications of trying to fix this.

Comment: Nice question. Incidentally, I think that there is more than a single inconsistency caused by operations internally starting with calling `.values`, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174030/pandas-to-dictrecords-generates-base-and-numpy-ints/50175192#50175192).

Comment: I've added an answer with the practical side of  the whole thing (there's a `casting` argument to `astype` that seems to be made to solve that particular issue). While a bit cryptic, I think the whole 'for backwards compatibility ' comes from the way certain languages like to represent single-element sequences as scalars and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `unsafe` default-value for the `casting`argument of `astype`. In the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) the argument `casting` is described as such:

"Controls what kind of data casting may occur. **Defaults to ‘unsafe’ for backwards compatibility.**" (my emphasis)

Any of the other possible castings return a `TypeError`.

```
a = np.empty((1,), object)
a[0] = np.array([1.2])
a.astype(float, casting='same_kind')
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

This is true for all castings except `unsafe`, namely: `no`, `equiv`, `safe`, and `same_kind`.